# Reshaping data frame to long list of key:values

Tags: r

I have a dataset `row data` in the following format:

```
Id Avg_bed_2017 staff_2014 staff_2015 staff_2016 staff_2017 outpatient_2013
1  460265      0.00000         NA         NA         NA         NA                      NA
2  16121       13.66667        497      508.5        515        505
```

and my goal is to reshape this into the following format:

```
Id category year  value 
1   Avg_bed 2017  460265
2   Avg_bed 2017  16121 
3   staff   2014  13.667
4   .....   ....  .....
```

For this I have defined a function `split.col.name(col)` that uses as input each name of column and splits it into the `category` and the `year` and returns them as list with two elements.

I then designed a function `split.col.row (rowdline)` then takes as input a row of the `row data` and returns a row of the latter table.

I tried then (1) to run `split.col.row (rowdline)` on the rows of `row data` (257K rows) and  (2) apply the `apply()` function on each row. The (1) is very slow and the (2) is not binding the rows properly (producing a matrix limited to the size of the input data whilst in this case the output would have much more rows). Maybe there is a more effective way to do this reshaping?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
# make sample data
set.seed(1839)
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  avgbed_2017 = rnorm(3), # note: rename this column
  staff_2014 = rnorm(3),
  staff_2015 = rnorm(3),
  outpatient_2013 = rnorm(3)
)

# gather and separate
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -id) %>% # gathers everything but id
  # if you wanna get rid of NA values, say na.rm = TRUE in gather
  separate("key", c("category", "year"), sep = "_")
```

Note that you have to rename `avg_bed_2017` to `avgbed_2017` for this to work. If I were better at regular expressions, I would make `sep` in `separate` be a regular expression that matches *only* the second occurrence of an underscore—perhaps someone else can show me how. To get around it, I just renamed the column above so that the only underscore is the one we want to split on.

---

Per @Dave2e:

```
set.seed(1839)
data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  avg_bed_2017 = rnorm(3),
  staff_2014 = rnorm(3),
  staff_2015 = rnorm(3),
  outpatient_2013 = rnorm(3)
) %>%
  gather("key", "value", -id) %>% 
  separate("key", c("category", "year"), sep = "_(?=[0-9]{4})")
```

Comment: If you use the look behind feature of regular expression, you can avoid renaming the columns: ` sep="_(?=[0-9]{4})"`  this assumes all columns end with a 4 digit year.